# Can I unlink in perl with a list from a unix find command?

Tags: find, perl, rm

Trying to delete thousands of files on multiple servers.
`rm` will not work.
Wrote a generic script to run from `cron` to delete on a regular basis:

```
...  
/bin/perl -e 'unlink ( <`find ${DIRECTORY} -name "*.${FILETYPE}" -type f -mtime +${DELETE_OLDER_THAN}`> ) or die "Nothing deleted\n" ' >> ${REMOVAL_LOGFILE} 2>&1  
...
```

I want to be very specific about what I am deleting.
I'm using perl because it's appears to be faster than `-exec rm {}` :/
Is `find` allowed in this context?

Comment: perl has a `find` module [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

Comment: There is also `find2perl` http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html

Comment: There is seldom if ever any reason to mix Perl with `find(1)`.  Perl's `File::Find` is generally much more versatile than `find(1)`.

Comment: I used perl -e unlink - worked well for what I wanted to accomplish

Answer (score 4):

If your `find` supports the `-delete` action you'll find this about as fast as you can go without spawning multiple delete processes:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -name "*.$FILETYPE" -type f -mtime +"$DELETE_OLDER_THAN" \
    -delete -print >> "$REMOVAL_LOGFILE" 2>&1
```

You'll find that `-exec rm {} \;` is slow because it creates a new process for every delete operation. If your `find` has it, `-exec rm {} +` would be faster because it would create one `rm` process for a considerable number of files. But fastest of all single-threaded solutions would be `-delete`.

With somewhat more complexity you could fork one `find .. -delete` process per directory, in a tree of directories, and have (at least some of) those running in parallel. But I don't know how many directories you're processing so I can't determine whether this would be a net gain.